# what does test_input mean in pregmatch when validating input data?

Tags: php, preg-match

i found this expression on a website explaining the use of pregmatch and this is part of their code:

```
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
  $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
}
```

What does test_input mean. i've looked for it everywhere i can't find its meaning.

Comment: It is a user defined function.

Comment: Best reference for PHP functions is the php manual http://us2.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=test_input&scope=quickref Utilize the search box if google. doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

> What does `test_input` mean?

It's a [user defined function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

> i've looked for it everywhere i can't find its meaning.

If it's not in the current file, it's likely [*included*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) elsewhere. It's possible it may be part of an extension. You could inspect the functions within an extension using [`get_extension_funcs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-extension-funcs.php).

Answer (score 0):

See this page:

[PHP 5 Forms - Required Fields - w3schools.com example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp)

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

[Full Example from w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_required)